# The material is not displayed in the preview and render

Tags: rendering, materials

When the material is attached, it is not displayed in the preview of the render and on the render.

I'm a beginner and I don't know much

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewport to see the material you would have to switch to "Material Preview" or "Render", since solid mode doesnt show materials.

[image]

Regarding the final render, it depends what render engine you are using.
If it is set to "Workbench", change it to "Eevee"

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped